# How to narrow the type of an upper-bounded type parameter in a state machine encoding?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, fsm, algebraic-data-types

Say I have a `Cake` that can cycle through a number of states:

```scala
sealed trait State extends Product with Serializable
object State {
    final case object Raw extends State
    final case class JustRight(temperature: Int) extends State
    final case class Burnt(charCoalContent: Double) extends State
}
final case class Cake[S <: State](name: String, state: S)
```

This is nice, because now I can make sure that I only try to put `Raw` cakes into the oven, instead of eating them right away.

But sometimes I just have a `Cake[State]` lying around and want to try to eat it, but only if it's in an edible state. I could of course always pattern match on `cake.state`, but I thought it should be possible to save myself a few keystrokes by adding a method `def narrow[S <: State]: Cake[State] => Option[Cake[S]]`.

However, now I'm struggling to actually implement that function. The compiler accepts `Try(cake.asInstanceOf[Cake[S]]).toOption`, but it seems that would always succeed (I guess because the type parameter is erased, and actually any type `A` would be accepted here, not just `S`). What seems to work is `Try(cake.copy(state = cake.state.asInstanceOf[S])).toOption`, but now I've made a superfluous copy of my data. Is there another better way? Or is that whole encoding maybe flawed from the get-go?

Comment: I don't understand why your `narrow` method can't pattern match, though. Using `asInstanceOf` with `Try` doesn't seem like a good approach, honestly.

Comment: It could, but that wouldn't eliminate the need to use `.copy`, right?

Comment: Oh, I see, you want to check if it's an `S`, not if it's a `JustRight`/`Burnt`. You could use an implicit parameter `=:=` perhaps.

Comment: Then again, how would I pattern match that? `S` is erased and cannot be observer in the matches

Comment: @user that won't work because the compile type is already `S`

Comment: I'm intrigued :) could you come up with an example using `=:=` @user?

Comment: Something like [this](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/SvNGAul6T6CU8l9MVWDJlA), maybe?

Comment: That does look interesting... I'll go read up on generalized type constraints very quickly. Why is the `null` default necessary? And if you'd add that as an answer I'd be totally willing to upvote and possibly accept :)  @user

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez That's probably the best approach - you should add that as an answer.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Yeah, I like that approach. Would you care to edit that into an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this problem using a **typeclass** that checks and casts *(in a typesafe way)* the type of the state.

```
sealed trait State extends Product with Serializable
object State {
    final case object Raw extends State
    type Raw = Raw.type
    final case class JustRight(temperature: Int) extends State
    final case class Burnt(charCoalContent: Double) extends State
  
    sealed trait Checker[S <: State] {
      def check(state: State): Option[S]
    }
    object Checker {
      private def instance[S <: State](pf: PartialFunction[State, S]): Checker[S] =
        new Checker[S] {
          val f = pf.lift
          override def check(state: State): Option[S] = f(state)
        }
      
      implicit final val RawChecker: Checker[Raw] = instance {
        case Raw => Raw
      }
      
      implicit final val JustRightChecker: Checker[JustRight] = instance {
        case s @ JustRight(_) => s
      }
      
      implicit final val BurntChecker: Checker[Burnt] = instance {
        case s @ Burnt(_) => s
      }
    }
}

final case class Cake[S <: State](name: String, state: S)

def narrow[S <: State](cake: Cake[State])(implicit checker: State.Checker[S]): Option[Cake[S]] =
  checker.check(cake.state).map(s => cake.copy(state = s))
```

Which you can use like this:

```
val rawCake: Cake[State] = Cake(name = "Foo", state = State.Raw)

narrow[State.Raw](rawCake)
// res: Option[Cake[State.Raw]] = Some(Cake(Foo,Raw))
narrow[State.JustRight](rawCake)
// res: Option[Cake[State.JustRight] = None
```

---

BTW if you want to avoid the `copy`, you may change `check` to just return **Boolean** and use a dirty `asInstanceOf`.

```
// Technically speaking it is unsafe, but it seems to work just right.
def narrowUnsafe[S <: State](cake: Cake[State])(implicit checker: State.Checker[S]): Option[Cake[S]] =
  if (checker.check(cake.state)) Some(cake.asInstanceOf[Cake[S]])
  else None
```

---

*(You can see the code running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/P8I84ErlQr6lIQyQZQYEfw/12))*

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the specific type of your `Cake`'s state at compile time, you might want to use `ClassTag` to check the type of your state instead, because throwing and catching `ClassCastException`s doesn't seem like a good idea to me:

```scala
def narrow[S <: State](cake: Cake[_])(implicit classTag: ClassTag[S]): Option[Cake[S]] =
  Option.when(classTag.runtimeClass.isInstance(cake.state))(cake.asInstanceOf[Cake[S]])
```

[Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Jl5XYrRsT56euYbGI7Cxig)

This works by checking if the cake's state is an instance of the erased class of `S`. If your states take type parameters, however, you may want to use `TypeTag` instead.

However, if you do know the specific type, you might want to use <s>`=:=`</s> `<:<` to check (`<:<` rejects `Cake[State]`):

```scala
def narrow[S <: State] = new NarrowFn[S]

class NarrowFn[S <: State] {
  def apply[S2 <: State](cake: Cake[S2])(implicit ev: S2 <:< S = null): Option[Cake[S]] =
    Option.when(ev != null)(cake.asInstanceOf[Cake[S]])
}
```

[Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/7IJavH3kScudJpwQXs8WXg)

Note that neither of these are great solutions, and I'd suggest just making a separate method for each case and use plain pattern matching to get your answer.

Comment: The problem is here `def apply[S2 <: State](cake: Cake[S2])` if my cake is **Cake[State]** then even if the underlying class is `S` we will not get the desired result. I will post the **typeclass** answer in a couple of hours.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez In the second example, it doesn't matter what the underlying type is, though, since we're only checking at compile time.

Comment: Right! but the question asked about having data with the wrong type :p